# Can I see my recently played song from Google Music somewhere?

Tags: browser, google-music

I am currently listening to music with my all access Google Music on my tablet while I am writing this on my computer.

**Is there any way I to view what songs were played recently, or what song is playing right now in Google Music** without looking at the device playing it? Preferably on the computer.

Comment: Can we assume that the computer would have to be logged into the account and access some form of account history or dashboard to know what's going on in the tablet?  I'm wondering if you might have better luck on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ (a little late for that with an active bounty).

Comment: This method is documented: google play music website > listen now > recent activity, or playlists > last added. Does this work? (I'm not a user of Google Music.)

Comment: @harrymc - No, that is different.  I don't want "last added".  I want "last played".

Comment: @fixer1234 - Yes, I've tried from the Play Music app on my Android phone, and I've tried from the music.google.com website (while logged in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is impossible without some sort of 3rd party software such as [music remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ubergrund.android.mr5&hl=en) for android. music remote only works from an android to another device. I cannot find any software for tablet to computer. sorry.

Comment: The link is broken, probably the program is not available any more.